# Levenstein search postgres

Tags: postgresql, search, levenshtein-distance

I want to have Full-Text Search without the stemming - it feels like too much of a naive approach.

What I want is:

```
select * from content order by levenstein_distance(document, :query_string)
```

I want it to be blazing fast.

I still want to have my queries / documents split by spaces.
Would the `GIN` index on `document` still be relevant?

Is this possible? Would it be blazing fast?

Answer (score 1):

There is no index support for that, so it would be slow.

Perhaps [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) can help, it provides similarity matching that can be supported by a GIN index.